# Hypothesis testing to determine if data was generated by Bayesian Network

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, bayesian-network, generative-models

If I have a Bayesian network, In my case made up of only Gaussian variables and discrete variables, and I have some data which may or may not have been generated by this network (as in, could have been sampled from it).

Is there any "hypothesis test" which could determine whether or not I can remove the possibility that this network generated the data?

Answer (score 1):

Can you generate repeated random samples from the Bayesian network and calculate a test statistic (e.g. some sort of distance metric) that measures how different the each random sample is from the data in question? If so, you can estimate the p-value for an effect of given size from the proportion of random samples giving the same or larger statistic, as Allen Downey describes [here](http://allendowney.blogspot.de/2016/06/there-is-still-only-one-test.html).